# How to catch update DOM event with angular?

Tags: angular, jquery-select2

I have table and there is select2 control in tablecell . 
in `ngAfterViewInit` method I'm calling something like `jQuery('.select2Class').select2(...);`
I have possibility to add new row in table
now the code is something like

```js
addNewRow(){
    this.rows.push({name:'new row'});
    setTimeout(function(){
        jQuery('#newSelect2Id').select2(...);
    },10);
}
```

I need to use `setTimeout` because there is no event `angularReady`.
I know its bad, but i don't know how to do it correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using jQuery directly like `jQuery('#newSelect2Id').select2(...);` create a dedicated custom element, for example `<select2-input></select2-input>`.

Then in component template you would have normal `*ngFor` directive rendering rows. Something like this:

```html
<tr *ngFor="let row of rows">
  <td>
    <select2-input 
        [options]="select2Options"
        (select)="row.selectedOption = $even.value"
    ></select2-input>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Now, about implementation of this custom element. The simplest implementation would be just implementing `OnInit` interface and initializing `nativeElement` with `$.fn.select2` plugin. You can also implement necessary inputs and outputs, like in above example you would probably want to pass some select2 options into component and react to `select2:select` event.